# Magento Frontend Dashboard Stuck Loading

Tags: magento2, error, image, dashboard

**Magento 2.2.5**

Attached are screenshots of the **errors** in **Chrome dev tools**:

jquery.js
[image: jquery.js]
loader.js
[image: loader.js]
[image]

Also:

There are some **images** being requested that are missing from an **S3 bucket** that are throwing out **403/404 errors**. I wouldn’t think that would cause the **dashboard** to continue loading without any results or timing out.

Comment: Please check the error log in '/var/report/' folder

Comment: Is there way to view the file where the data is more readable?

Answer (score 0):

A database connection was missing from env.php.